# How to run macro when data changes in sheet in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am using Excel to fetch live data from web into an Excel sheet and pushing it into a SQL Server Database using macro. The macro code is executing manually. The Excel sheet data gets refreshed every minute. I have to run this macro when the data gets refreshed from the web into the sheet. Can somebody please help me to understand how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about stopping auto refresh from web and put it as part of the macro?

or try adding the macro for worksheet change, explained here -  [How to run a macro when certain cells change in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/213612)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.EnableEvents = False
     Call MyOtherSub
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You can drop this in the worksheet module for the sheet being changed. Note the `.EnableEvents` statements - these are very important in ensuring you don't wind up in an infinite loop if your called procedure changes something.